# why do bit operations not work correctly

Tags: c, bitmask, vxworks, powerpc

I'm at a complete loss! Why does my code not work as expected?
I have the following code:

```
UINT64 tmpA = 0;
UINT64 tmpB = 0; 
UINT64 alarmed_lans = 0;
int foprtmsk[2]={0};
switch_fo_prtmsk_getptr(foprtmsk); 
tmpA = foprtmsk[1];                            
tmpB = foprtmsk[0];                            
gDbgLog("tmpA <%016llx>",tmpA);                
gDbgLog("tmpB <%016llx>",tmpB);                
gDbgLog("alarmed_lans <%016llx>",alarmed_lans);
alarmed_lans &= ((tmpA<<32) |tmpB);            
gDbgLog("alarmed_lans <%016llx>",alarmed_lans);
```

and the log produced looks like:

```
|0x1f604|7857[us]|fpga-alarm|fpga_faultlocalizer|tmpA <ffffffffeffeffff>
|0x1f6cb|7861[us]|fpga-alarm|fpga_faultlocalizer|tmpB <ffffffffffffffff>
|0x1f741|7863[us]|fpga-alarm|fpga_faultlocalizer|alarmed_lans <3003000000000000>
|0x1f7b8|7865[us]|fpga-alarm|fpga_faultlocalizer|alarmed_lans <3003000000000000>
```

Now, I'm wondering, why does the bitmask not get applied properly???
I'd expect to see

```
|0x1f7b8|7865[us]|fpga-alarm|fpga_faultlocalizer|alarmed_lans <2002000000000000>
```

What's going on here?

CPU: PPC85XXe500
compiler: `diab`
OS: `VxWorks`

Comment: You never initialized `alarmed_lans` so your program causes undefined behaviour

Comment: And don't use homebrew types if there are standard types. Use `uint64_t`, etc.

Comment: @M.M Sorry, I missed that, it actually gets initialized to 0, I fixed this now

Comment: You fixed `alarmed_lans` not being initialized, but now it makes even less sense. Where does `alarmed_lans` get set to `3003000000000000`?

Comment: @Olaf There is `UINT64` is defined as follows: `typedef uint64_t UINT64;` What speaks against usage of this?

Comment: @cerr: Which added benefit does it have compared to using the standard alias? Note that in C one cannot define new types (my comment was a bit imprecise). Another aspect is that all-uppercase is commonly used for macros and _enum-constants_ only. This is one of the few well accepted naming conventions. Concentrate on writing readable code.

Comment: @Olaf `struct` can be used to define new types in C

Comment: @M.M: A _struct (or union) specifier_ does not create a new type, Two identical such specifiers denote the same type ("compatible types"). And `typedef` as used here is just syntactic sugar, defining an alias for a type.

Comment: Yeah... the same new type. `struct S { int x, y; };` makes a new type `struct S` that did not previously exist.

Comment: @Olaf part of writing readable code is also to align with the conventions used in different places of the application, is it not? These `typedefs` weren't added by me and they're used all over the application.

Comment: @cerr: Yes. And it only should use custom conventions if there are no standard or well accepted conventions. That's all my comment says. If your application uses such homebrew aliases, it is badly designed. Not the first one I see and most likely not the last. But maybe pointing that out might avoid one bad coded program.

Comment: @olaf UINT64 is the standard (little s) definition used in vxworks, which may well (and often is) being compiled without access to the stdint types. UINT64 _is_ the standard and well accepted convention used in this environment

Comment: @mjs: If it is standard, please provide a reference to the standard document. Otherwise it might be common in vxworks, but it is not standard. Considering the age of that OS, it was clear it is some legacy stuff.

Comment: @Olaf hence standard with a little s, meaning convention

Comment: @mjs: "standard" is always written with lower `s` in English. What you mean is a norm. - If you are a native German speaker: they are perfect false friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
alarmed_lans &= ((tmpA<<32) |tmpB);
```

- `alarmed_lans` was never initialised. Using it results in undefined behaviour.

  - tmpB is 0xfffff… (all 1s)
  - OR that with anything and you get all 1s again.
  - AND that with `x` and you get `x`

In theory, you should get the uninitialised value of `alarmed_lans`, but in practice, the compiler is allowed to do anything, including the invocation of [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html)

Comment: @cerr then where is the value for `alarmed_lans` set?

Answer (score 1):

```
alarmed_lans &= ((tmpA << 32) | tmpB);
                              ^            // change this | to &
alarmed_lans &= ((tmpA << 32) & tmpB);
```